# How to find string and then divide the token while reading the file line by line using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
I have tried to do like this
```

Inputfile contains the file which has to be read

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%INPUTFILE%) do (
    SET my_line=%%A
    SET my_line=%my_line:#define ACCEL_PRESENT%
    findstr /C:"define ACCEL_PRESENT" 
    if %errorlevel%==0 ( SET my_line=%%A
    call :parse_it
    )

)

:parse_it
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-6 delims= " %%1 in ('%my_line%') do (
    echo %%3 > t.txt
)
```

I am getting nothing from the above code.Can someone help me with the desired results

Comment: SET my_line=%my_line:#define ACCEL_PRESENT% here I am looking for the line but I want to search for the string

Comment: Syntax error? : It is `%var:search=replace%` not `%var:search%`! What do you want to do? To remove `#define ACCEL_PRESENT` string?

Comment: Classic delayed expansion issue

Comment: As `%my_line%` is a string don't enclose it into single-quotes, but into DOUBLE-QUOTES!

Comment: `findstr /c:"string"` will give you nothing!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variables in batch not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: Please provide an example of your input file and Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please learn, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%INPUTFILE%) do (
    set "my_line=%%A"
    set "my_line=!my_line:#define ACCEL_PRESENT=!"
    echo !my_line! | findstr /C:"define ACCEL_PRESENT"
    IF !errorlevel! EQU 0 ( SET "my_line=%%A" && call:parse_it )
)

:parse_it
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-6 delims= " %%A in ("%my_line%") do echo %%C > t.txt

rem exit /b
```

I hope you wanted to delete string `#define ACCEL_PRESENT`.

Also, say me if `%my_line%` is a command (I don't think so, so I removed single-quotes and I added double-quotes).

Better to use letter variables in `for` loops!